# NativeActivity and Classloader

Tags: java, android

I have a custom class extends `Classloader`. It runs well when android build sdk less than 24，but it crash when android build sdk equal 24, why ??

The log is :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mumayi.plugin.manager.FrameworkClassLoader cannot be cast to dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader
    at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:164)
    at com.netease.neox.NeoXClient.onCreate(NeoXClient.java:18)
    at com.netease.zmq.Client.onCreate(Client.java:180)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Comment: After my test, I found out it running well when it not load class ‘nativeActivity’ or it's child class.But on the contrary，it'll crash.